# Pause an ad with IMASDK, android?

Tags: android, exoplayer, imasdk

In my app, I am using exoplayer with IMA extension. The integration works perfectly fine. I want to pause the add on user action basically displaying a play/pause button while the ad is displayed or playing. I have integrated the UI design for the play pause and its visibility works perfectly fine.

How do I add the functionality to pause or play the on the touch of button.
In the SDK I found the pause and play method in the AdsManager and ImaAdsLoader class but those do not seem to work.

```
adsManager.resume();
            imaAdsLoader.resumeAd();
```

Are there any other methods exposed by the SDK or other way to pause the advertisement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the exoplayer we have a method on player setPlayWhenReady(boolean) with boolean argument. For both player and ads player this method seems to work.
Simply setting it to false pauses the ad and on true resumes the ad.

```
setPlayWhenReady(false); //pause ad
setPlayWhenReady(true); //resume ad
```